# My jquery animation is not working

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery
I don't know why my animation is not working
This is my Script
I have also created a fiddle in case there is something wrong with my CSS
Link to my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Updatebaba/gbs92cxh/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#next").on('click',function(){
        var block=$("#moving_box1");
        block.animate({left:250px},"slow","linear",function(){
            alert("yehi");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't include the javascript

Comment: now i have  included it sorry.

Comment: No you still haven't. The fiddle has HTML in the javascript column.

Comment: Instead of jsfiddle, put the example here with [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)

Comment: I don't understand why you're getting downvoted, it's a solvable problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Updatebaba/gbs92cxh/8/ here it is

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. The issue is with your `<div id="#next">` replace this with `<div id="next">`. Also in jQuery you have not add quote `'left': '250px'` so i have add that too.

I have updated code. Please check here :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#next").on('click',function(){
    var block=$("#moving_box1");
    block.animate({'left': '250px'},"slow","linear",function(){
        alert("yehi");
    });
});
});
```

```css
#box{
 display:block;
 width:1060px;
 align:center;
 height:400px;
 padding:2px;
 margin:2px;
 border:1px solid red;
 
 
}
#moving_box1{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 left:0px;
 width:300px;
 height:350px;
 padding:2px;
 margin:4px;
 border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
 <div id="moving_box1">
 </div>
 <div id="next">
 <p>Next</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should also point out that you wrapped the 250px with quotations.

Comment: Quotes aren't even needed if the pixel value is removed. Neither are they around the property.